# Handlebars, nested each with parallel arrays

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I have two arrays like below.

```
const arr1 = [ 1, 2 ]
const arr2 = [[1,3,5],[2,4,6]]
```

I want loop through `arr1` and inside loop I want to loop through `arr2[arr1.index]`.
My attempt is below, but of course it is not working:

```
{{#each arr1}}
    {{#each arr2.[ @index ]}} //index is from #each arr1
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that result by doing:

```
{{#each arr2}}
    {{#each this}}
       {{ this }}
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well answer is `lookup` helper and `../` for reaching parent scope.

```
{{#each arr1}}
    {{#each (lookup ../arr2 @index)}} //index is from #each arr1
    {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```